# Problem with threads in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, md5

I have a problem with threads in Delphi. When using TIdHashMessageDigest5 in order to get MD5 from a big file, I have noticed that it takes too much time, and ends up in an application freeze.

I'm thinking about using a separate thread. So I have made a little form where I insert a simple message, a button and a progress bar in style pbstMarquee. I start a thread on the show event of this form.

My problem is: I want to close this form when HashStreamAsHex has finished reading successfully, but how can I do this? I tried calling the Close method on synchronize, but then the form is closed without waiting for that thread to finish. I also tried to use the waitfor method, without success.

Someone can help me with this, giving me some example, or link or similar?

Thanks very much and sorry for my bad english.

```
About form:
-----------
procedure TFormProgress.FormProgressOnShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressThread := TProgressThread.Create(True);
  ProgressThread.Form := FormProgress;
  ProgressThread.FileSrc := uFileSrc;
  ProgressThread.Start;
end;

About thread:
-------------
procedure TProgressThread.Execute;
begin
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  uFileMD5 := GetFileMd5 (uFileSrc)  // function is definited in other unit.
  Self.WaitFor;
  Synchronize(DoSync);
end;

procedure TProgressThread.DoSync;
begin
  oForm.Close;
end;

GetFileMd5 è so defined:

function GetFileMD5(const Src: TFileName): UnicodeString;
var
  Md5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  FileSrc: TFileStream;
  StrMd5: UnicodeString;
begin
  Md5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    FileSrc := TFileStream.Create(Src, fmOpenRead);
    try
      StrMd5 := Md5.HashStreamAsHex(FileSrc);
    finally
      FileSrc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Md5.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: hello, form is a modal form, but i need close form when HashStreamAsHex method return md5 of a file. This method è called in a thread. For big file infact it take several minutes and freeze.

Comment: Can tell me as diplay correctly code of delphi with indent? as you see i have some problem :( where i mistake? thanks very much.

Comment: select the block of code and press {} button

Comment: forgive me, where is the {} button? i have searched in all page but not found :(

Comment: When you are editing the code there is a toolbar of buttons above the edit box. Click the one that looks like {}

Comment: hello, here tell me that i can't post other question as answer to this becouse need just 100 etc, so i can only write as comment :( up me i read: please avoid extended etc.. and under about characters left

Comment: Click the Edit button under your question. Paste in the code. Select the code. Press the {} button. Save Edits.

Comment: Are you making your main form a modal form? Bad idea! Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

No one has pointed this out, inside the function no value was returned.

```
function GetFileMD5(const Src: TFileName): UnicodeString;
var
  Md5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  FileSrc: TFileStream;
  StrMd5: UnicodeString;
begin
  Md5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    FileSrc := TFileStream.Create(Src, fmOpenRead);
    try
      StrMd5 := Md5.HashStreamAsHex(FileSrc);
    finally
      FileSrc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Md5.Free;
  end;
  // You are missing this line, calculated md5 was never returned
  Result := StrMd5;
end;
```

Comment: +1 Sorry, I saw this answer after I updated my own with the same observation.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, `Self.WaitFor` will never return. That waits until the thread has terminated, i.e. its `Execute` method has completed. But that can't happen because it stops and waits for itself.  You should simply remove the call to `WaitFor`.

I also wonder whether or not `Close` is the correct way to terminate the form. If it really is a modal form then you should use `oForm.ModalResult := mrOK`.

---

I've just seen your edit which includes the definition of `GetFileMD5`. This function doesn't return a value. You should receive a compiler warning telling you of this—read the compiler warnings, they are very valuable.  Write `GetFileMD5` like this:

```
function GetFileMD5(const Src: TFileName): string;
var
  Md5: TIdHashMessageDigest5;
  FileSrc: TFileStream;
begin
  Md5 := TIdHashMessageDigest5.Create;
  try
    FileSrc := TFileStream.Create(Src, fmOpenRead);
    try
      Result := Md5.HashStreamAsHex(FileSrc);
    finally
      FileSrc.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Md5.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: i have tried to so, but nothing, when i run application the form is closed in less of a second too with file biggest and uFileMD5 not return md5 of file (of course if i run function only it work correctly). What i do?

Comment: What happens when you step through `TProgressThread.Execute`? What does GetFileMd5 return?

Comment: done but nothing, form closed after less of a second every, as if not execute function for get md5 :( some idea?

Comment: What happens when you step through TProgressThread.Execute? What does GetFileMd5 return? Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: My guess is that the MD5 calculation is working. I think it should be quick even for typical large files.

Comment: I think I have the answer. You were not returning anything from `GetFileMD5`! See the update.

Comment: @Marcello It seems to me that you haven't yet learnt about the debugger. I strongly recommend that you learn how to use it because it will make it easy for you to track down silly lapses like this.

Answer (score 1):

My guess: the form is opened in Modal mode (form.ShowModal) and there is something that assigns the form.ModalResult before the calculation has completed. 
  This would cause the istantaneus closing of the form.

Maybe did you place a TBitButton having the modalresult propery set to mrOk? if you have done so, pressing that button will close the form as soon as the onClick event handler terminates, no matter if there is a running thread.

Answer (score 1):

[This is](http://www.nickhodges.com/MultiThreadingInDelphi/ToC.html) is a good documentation about threading in delphi, with examples, situations. Start reading from the beginning, and I'm sure you will find the answer by yourself. You don't have to read everything, just the first 4-5 chapters.

Comment: The link no longer works, it tells the domain is for sale. Please consider updating or removing the link, as it currently shows advertisement not related to the topic.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin: thanks for reporting, found a working link.

Answer (score 1):

### About the WaitFor

As the people have correctly pointed out, you should not call "Self.WaitFor;".

The "WaitFor" is designed to be called from other threads. The thread may not wait for himself - this is contrary to the logic. For example, I cannot wait for myself - I'm always ready for myself! ;-) So is the thread.

### The Best Way to Close a Form From a Thread

The best way to close the form is to send a "WM_CLOSE" message to its window handle using "PostMessage".

Instead of the "Synchronize(DoSync);" do the following: "PostMessage(FormProgress.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);".

The "FormProgress" here is the variable that holds the pointer to the "TFormProgress" class instance. Consequently, the "DoSync" is not needed.

### On Synchronize

As a rule, the "Synchronize" shows that something is bad about the application design. It's better to design applications without any "Synchronize" at all.